# multiple instance of same activity

Tags: android, android-activity

hello I am new to android and I need your help.
I have a home activity and one friend activity. From home I am creating friend activity. how can I have more than one instance of friend , save their state and switch between them. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

[check here How activiity an task handaled in android](http://mobisynth.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/android-tasks-and-activity-backstack/)

i think dont create new instances instead save the state in Sharedpreferences and then use that saved state while you want to change.

also another way in your home activity call this method

```
startActivityforResult(intent,code);
```

and every time create new instance of friend class and while coming back to home just pass the

```
setResult(code);
```

which can be checked at call back method of Home activity.

```
onActivityResult();
```

Comment: thanks for simple answer but I  will have to check it I will get back soon with my result.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActivityGroup --> getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id, intent);
```